# Android service is silently stopped

Tags: android, service, process

My application uses a service which is supposed to work like a clock - it broadcasts a tick, then uses handler to notify itself about next tick. Handler message is removed when screen is turned off and resumes when screen is turned on to avoid doing anything when suspended. The service also updates a notification at some rate.

And sometimes the service simply gets stopped. I turn on the screen and I see a really outdated notification. The application that uses data from service (through binding) shows outdated information. There is no service in process list. And there is no error message.

Service's `onDestroy()` method contains a code to show notification like "I'm killed, please restart me" but that doesn't get shown.

I know I can use `AlarmManager` to periodically restart my service and I'll probably have to do that, but if there's any other solution, I'd be happy to know it.

Interesting fact: I never had the issue on any emulator, nor on my previous phone (Motorola Milestone running 2.2), nor had any complaints from several Samsung Galaxy S (2 and 3) users. The only person reporting the bug was owner of LG phone. Now I'm getting the same "sudden server stop" on Nexus 4. LG conspiracy?

Comment: would you like to post code for `onStartCommand` method?

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/aragaer/jtt_android/blob/master/src/com/aragaer/jtt/JTTService.java#L85

Comment: I don't know why, but I got problem with `Handler` inside a service too. I moved to `AlarmManager` and it was fixed.

Comment: did you think of acquiring CPU WakeLock in your service?

Comment: No, since I don't need my service running when device is going to get suspended, but I need my service awakened when device is.